# How to merge multiple lines in a csv file using Perl

Tags: perl, csv

Please help me in writing a code which will merge the lines of a csv file. My csv file is as shown below,

```
output.csv

abc,1,2,3,4,5
abc,3,5,60,3
abc,4,5,6
def,2,5,6,7
def,3,4,5,6
```

This is just an example. my csv file data keeps on changing each time. So, it is not limited to abc ( 3 rows) or def( 2 rows). 
Please help me to put the code so my csv file displays as shown below:

```
output.csv

abc,1,2,3,4,5,3,5,60,3,4,5,6
def,2,5,6,7,3,4,5,6
```

I tried reading csv using Text::CSV and tried hash. But I got stuck up when I tried to convert array to hash. I'm little confused here.Please help me out.

Comment: We would like to see your code

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the first field doesn't contain commas:

```
perl -nle '
    ($key,$vals) = /^([^,]+),(.*)/;
    push @{$final_lines{$key}},$vals;
    END{
        for $key (sort keys %final_lines){
            print join ",",$key,@{$final_lines{$key}}
        }
    }
' < input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

open my $ifh, '<', 'input.csv' or die $!;
open my $ofh, '>', 'output.csv' or die $!;

while (<$ifh>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split /,/;
  my $key = shift @F;
  push @{$hash{$key}}, @F;
}

foreach (sort keys %hash) {
  print $ofh "$_," . join (',', @{$hash{$_}}) . "\n";
}

close $ifh;
close $ofh;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
while (<>) {
    $hash{$1} .= $2 if /(.+?)(,.+)/;
}

print "$_$hash{ $_ }\n" for sort keys %hash;
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
abc,1,2,3,4,5,3,5,60,3,4,5,6
def,2,5,6,7,3,4,5,6
```

Hope this helps!