# How to merge lines into a csv file

Tags: perl, csv, cgi

I have a csv file with several lines where first field is duplicated and from other field only one is actually filled (and always different)
I need to write a perl CGI that merge those lines into a single one
The csv file look like the example below

```
aaaa,3
aaaa,,5
aaaa,,,1
aaaa,,,,3
bb,2
bb,,4
bb,,,,,,,,,,6
cc,,,,,,5
dd,5
```

What I want in output should be something like:

```
aaaa,3,5,1,3
bb,2,4,,,,,,,,6
cc,,,,,,5
dd,5
```

I'm pretty new on perl language but from a bit of research i did I think using hash seems the way to go but I still didn't fully get how those work, and please remember i need this inside a perl cgi , so a single command line wont' help me

So i grab this piece of code from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846611/how-to-merge-multiple-lines-in-a-csv-file-using-perl)

```
open my $ifh, '<', "input_file" or die $!;
open my $ofh, '>', "output_file" or die $!;
while (<$ifh>) {
    chomp;
    my @F = split /,/;
    my $key = shift @F;
    push @{$hash{$key}}, @F;
}

foreach (sort keys %hash) {
    print $ofh "$_," . join (',', @{$hash{$_}}) . "\n";
}

close $ifh;
close $ofh;
```

but it's just adding field on the same line from the duplicate, I need to write in the actual undefined field

Comment: _"i need this inside a perl cgi "_ -- Sorry that is not the way this site works. StackOverflow is not a "write the code for me" site.  YOU are expected to make the effort and we will help when you encounter a problem.  But we won't do the work for you. Please visit the [help] and read [ask]

Comment: please show us what you tried, the error you get, where exactly you are stuck, but don't ask us to write your code ;)

Comment: When you say "I need this inside a perl CGI", do you actually mean that you need this to work as a web app? Because there are far better ways to write a web app in Perl than using CGI.

Comment: And even it you need this as a web application, the best way to write it is to a) write it as a command line program, and b) put a web front-end on your command line processing.

Comment: There are probably better way but this is going to integrate into something else which is already in CGI so not a choice of technology to use here

Comment: @toolic: All of the fields must be split in order to aggregate the latest non-blank value for each of them.

Comment: @Cris: *"not a choice of technology to use here"* Read again what [**Dave Cross** had to say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756626/how-to-merge-lines-into-a-csv-file#comment82476082_47756626). Get your code working as a command-line program and then integrate it into your CGI code. There is very little boilerplate or waste when writing Perl command-line code (it's not like Java or C++) and you will mostly be adding to it to get it working within CGI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer from **Dave Cross**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47757800/622310)
is excellent, but it relies on each line of data being longer than all preceding ones for the same key, which isn't assured by your question

Here's a very similar program that fixes that, and also keeps track of the order that the keys appear in the source data so that it can be reproduced on output

This program expects the path to the input CSV file as a parameter on the command line and prints the output to STDOUT. You can redirect the output on the command line

Writing this as a CGI application is far too broad a question. You need to do what you can and ask *specific* questions here if you get stuck

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ( @keys, %data );

while ( <> ) {
    next unless /\S/;
    chomp;
    my @newline = split /,/;
    my $key = $newline[0];

    if ( my $line = $data{ $key } ) { # Update any previously-blank fields

        for my $i ( 0 .. $#newline ) {

            $line->[$i] = $newline[$i] unless length $line->[$i] // '';
        }
    }
    else { # Build the first instance of this key

        $data{ $key } = \@newline;
        push @keys, $key;
    }
}

print join( ',', @{ $data{$_} } ), "\n" for @keys;
```

#### output

```
aaaa,3,5,1,3
bb,2,4,,,,,,,,6
cc,,,,,,5
dd,5
```

Comment: "The answer from Dave Cross is excellent, but it relies on each line of data being longer than all preceding ones for the same key" - I don't think that's true. It just relies on each new piece of data being in a position that isn't previously occupied. I just tried mixing up the order of the input records and it still worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

The bit about merging the values from different lines interested me enough to have a go at it. Here's what I've done. Others may well be able to improve my solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($key, @values) = split /,/;

  if ($data{$key}) {
    # It seems we can be sure that the new value
    # we're adding will be the last element on the line.
    $data{$key}[$#values] = $values[$#values];
  } else {
    $data{$key} = \@values;
  }
}

for my $k (sort keys %data) {
  say join ',', $k, map { $_ // '' } @{$data{$k}};
}

__DATA__
aaaa,3
aaaa,,5
aaaa,,,1
aaaa,,,,3
bb,2
bb,,4
bb,,,,,,,,,,6
cc,,,,,,5
dd,5
```

The output I get is:

```
aaaa,3,5,1,3
bb,2,4,,,,,,,,6
cc,,,,,,5
dd,5
```

Converting this to use CGI for input and output is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your code like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @F = split ',';
    my $key = $F[0];       
    for my $i (0..$#F) {
        $hash{$key}->[$i] //= $F[$i];   
    }
}

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    print join(',',@{$hash{$key}})."\n";
}

__DATA__
aaaa,3
aaaa,,5
aaaa,,,1
aaaa,,,,3
bb,2
bb,,4
bb,,,,,,,,,,6
cc,,,,,,5
dd,5
```

`$#F` is the array address of the last element, so `(0..$#F)` is a range of the address in @F. this lets you assign the elements from @F into the same address of another array (in this case, `$hash{$key}` is an anonymous array, aka an arrayref, and `${$hash{$key}}[$i]` accesses the $i element of that array).

`$hash{$key}->[$i] //= $F[$i]` means only assign to the element if it's not already defined.

Comment: `${$hash{$key}}[$i]` is more commonly written `$hash{$key}->[$i]` or `$hash{$key}[$i]`.

Comment: This is definitely what i was looking for, indeed tried the script stand alone and it work perfectly, I included the code inside the CGI part and the join return a blank value and can't get why, the hash array is populated correctly but it just return just the new line char, I tried modify the foreach to print   like this           `foreach (sort keys %hash) {
    #print "Value is".@hash($key)."<br>";
    print "My hash @{$hash{$key}}<br>";
    print $ofh join(',',@{$hash{$key}})."\n";
   } `

Comment: @Cris: Comments on Stack Overflow are deliberately unformatted to discourage people from using them to share anything but the smallest of code snippets. It sounds like you have a solution to the question you originally asked. If you now need help integrating that into a CGI program, then it probably makes sense to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @DaveCross thanks and good point on the arrarref, I changed it.